# How to stop app from sending user to MainActivity when SignedUp?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a registration Activity that allows the user to be sign up, and in that Activity I have fragments. The first fragment is for the user to input they're info then after passing multiple requirements the app creates the user like this

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registration Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        //else Authentication Successful
                        ConfirmEmail nextFrag = new ConfirmEmail();
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayoutEmailPassword, nextFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    }
                });
```

My problem is when I try to switch to the next fragment(for email verification) it just launches my MainActivity.

This is the activity of my fragment

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    Fragment fragment = new EmailPassword();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayoutSignUp, fragment).commit();


}
}
```

Comment: What is nextFrag? is this the mainActivity

Comment: @BhanuPrakashPasupula the nextFrag is another fragment to confirm the email not MainActivity